# Текст и картинка единая ссылка

Tags: html, css

Как сделать картинку и текст под ней единой ссылкой ?

Comment: Таким образом картинка отдельно от текста получается .

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы не было прогала ссылки между картинкой и текстом

Comment: Извините . Не знаю как написать ещё.  Наводишь на картинку курсор появляется знак ссылки. Начинаю вести курсор вниз к тексту который под картинкой, и вот в промежутке между картинкой и текстом, курсор становится обычной стрелочкой. Это конечно мелочь , но хочется чтобы все пространство этого блока было ссылкой . Извините за такое объяснение .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
a {
width:250px;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
background:grey;
text-decoration:none;
color:orange;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108919/Текст-и-картинка-единая-ссылка">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Foto" />
  <span>Я ссылка</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Опять извиняюсь за глупые вопросы, как может быть текс и картинка единой ссылкой ?

Comment: inline-block помогло ! Благодарю !!!